# TFS2017: Create a code review request through api

Tags: c#, tfs-sdk

Is there any way to create a complete `Code Review Request` on a changeset (as it works through the Visual Studio Team Explorer -> with email to reviewer(s) who are able to comment the changes) using the .NET library `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client`?

P.S. Through my research I know it seems possible with the `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient` using the [Discussion Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/hh985616(v%3Dvs.120)), but I am looking for a solution using the "new" API.

Comment: Do you mean REST API?

Comment: Yes. As far as I know the library i mentioned (Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client) uses the REST API in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start a code review by creating a code review request work item (use the general WIT api to create this type of WIT). Get a code review through REST API and look at the code review request work item that gets created to see how the fields need to be set. For example:

```
POST http://tfs2017:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/{TeamProject}/_apis/wit/workitems/$Code%20Review%20Request?api-version=3.2

Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

  [
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": null,
    "value": "codereview452"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.State",
    "from": null,
    "value": "Requested"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Reason",
    "from": null,
    "value": "New"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.CodeReview.ContextType",
    "from": null,
    "value": "Changeset"
  },
   {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.CodeReview.Context",
    "from": null,
    "value": "452"
  },
   {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.AssignedTo",
    "from": null,
    "value": "xxxx"
  },
   {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateCode",
    "from": null,
    "value": "0"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.CodeReview.ContextCode",
    "from": null,
    "value": "2"
  }
]
```

The actual comments on the code review need to use the discussion service.

Comment: Yeah I have done that already using the workItemTrackingHttpClient, but it won't send out an email to the reviewer with the changes.

Comment: Have you also created corresponding code review response work item?

Comment: Yes I did, but I did not receive any email notification (thats what I'm looking for). The changeset seems also to be lined correctly as an artifactlink.

Comment: Are you able to receive email notification when you create a code request in Team Explorer?

Comment: Ok, I have solved the problem. There were issues with notifications in general... Now I am receiving notification emails on the Code Review Request (generated over API). Sorry for the inconvenience and thank you for your suggestions!